# Remove 'private' and 'pending review' options from post status dropdown

Tags: post-status

I don't know how to remove these two options (private and pending review), for non admin users. This is a custom post type.

[image]

Comment: Select all posts -> bulk edit -> apply

Comment: It looks like this is [inline-edit-status](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L1784). You can see there's an option 'Scheduled' there too which appears to be unconditionally removed by [inline-edit-post.js](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.1/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js#L136) (!). It may be possible to hook into this too by overriding properties of window.inlineEditPost on the page but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Thats's probably because I removed the set status date via the wp_insert_post_data function. But I can't find an adequate hook for removing these post statuses. All I want for any post status is publish, draft and trash.